# OpenSolaris livecd, NForce NIC driver, and NTFS USB mounting

Tags: solaris, opensolaris, live-cd, solaris-10

I'm attempting to install OpenSolaris 2009.06 on my server. Before I do I would like to test that everything works and am running in to problems.

It has an Abit AN-M2 motherboard with an NForce chipset. The driver config utility says that I need a third-party driver and links me to http://homepage2.nifty.com/mrym3/taiyodo/eng/. Scrolling to the bottom, I have downloaded both tgzs just in case.

Now the fun part: The only way to get this on to the computer is via a USB drive since I can't access the network. Also, install CD in the drive otherwise I'd just burn them to DVD. Since my USB key is NTFS formatted I cannot mount it since the install CD seems to be lacking NTFS drivers which require more downloaded packages.

What should I do?

---

The server will simply be a dumb NAS and I know that there exists other OpenSolaris-based flavors such as Nexenta but from what I read the stock install is likely the best. If this is not the case and pursuing a different flavor is required or better I will also accept that as an answer (but please don't jump straight to it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Format the USB drive as FAT32

Comment: Is the FAT filesystem support baked into the install CD for sure?

Comment: Oh, livecd, sorry I missed that part. Probabably not... but there's one way to find out

Comment: Well the live environment recognized the FAT USB key and automounted it. Too bad neither gcc or suncc seem to be accessible, however. I'm going to go ahead with the install assuming that they'll be available in the actual OS. I've been dealing with complex stuff setting up all the hardware and controller cards who knew the answer would be so simple. Thank you for your fresh-thinking mind.

Comment: Gcc isn't bundled in the CD distribution but shouldn't be required to install a driver.

Comment: It seems there is a bug with the nge/nfo drivers too: http://www.opensolaris.org/jive/thread.jspa?messageID=448365#448365